# Convert CityGML

Tags: convert, 3d, citygml

I get CityGML Data from an OpenData Portal of a German Federal State.

Unfortunately I only have a Basic ArcGIS License, so I can't work with the Data Interoperability Extension.

I'm fine in working with ArcGIS, but not with Python.

Is there any way to convert the CityGML into a data type that ArcGIS can read?

Edit:
This is an example Data:
http://geoportal.geoportal-th.de/3dgebaeude/LoD2/LoD2_634_5616_2_TH.zip

My main goal is to load the Data of the buildings into an ArcMap Pro Scene, so I can create a 3D-Map. So I'd prefer to convert the CityGML into a gdb.

Comment: Give us test data, please.

Comment: I just tried reading the CityGML demo dataset from the https://www.citygml.org/samplefiles/ site into QGIS - it loads but you only get 2d geometry.

Comment: Maybe related: https://3d.bk.tudelft.nl/svitalis/citygml/gdal/2017/07/24/messing-around-with-citygml-on-gdal-2.2.html

Comment: Please decide which of the two Desktop GIS products you wish to ask about in this question. That way you can describe precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I updated my question, sorry for the inaccuracy

Comment: You are still asking about both QGIS or ArcGIS, you should tailor the question for one of QGIS or ArcGIS.

Comment: Now I erased QGIS